# Unable to receive correct http request until button click

Tags: java, android, http

I'm in android studio trying to make an api call by making an http GET request to a particular url, and setting some text to a value from that response. I have a function that `getFutureData` makes this call and calls other functions to set the text. The function is called during `onStart()` as well as from a button click.

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        display_location = findViewById(R.id.location);
        location_button = findViewById(R.id.refresh_location);

        getFutureData();  //the function in question
        location_button.setOnClickListener(v -> getFutureData());
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    void getFutureData() {
        double[] lat_lon = getLocation();
        String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + lat_lon[0]
                + "&lon=" + lat_lon[1]
                + "&appid=" + AppId;

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, response -> setLocation(response), error -> Log.d("ERROR", "Connection Error"));
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    double[] getLocation(){
        FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //permission not granted, must request location permission from user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1);
        }
        fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, location -> {
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        });

        double[] loc = {latitude,longitude};
        return loc;
    }
```

When the function runs on its own in `onStart`, it returns the api's equivalent of no data received:

```
"city":{"id":6295630,"name":"Earth","coord":{},"population":2147483647,"timezone":0,"sunrise":1566108041,"sunset":1566151650}
```

This api is meant to return weather for a specific location, and `Earth` is intended to be the nearest town/city of the specified coordinates. What I'm confused about is why I'm receiving that response when calling the function alone, but when I call the function from a button click, it returns the correct json string for my location, considering I'm calling the exact same function either way.

I did attempt to add a `location_button.performClick()` to my `onStart` method but no dice. I also tried adding a delay on the initial function call in case it was requesting too early, but that did not solve anything either. I'm not quite sure which way to look now for issues?

Comment: `getLocation()` how does this work ? Does it return the same thing when it's called in `onStart()` and via the button ?

Comment: Yep, it's only ever called from ```getFutureData()```, and I just added it in case it helps

Comment: Can you print the return value of `getLocation()` when it's called ?

Comment: Yep, here's the output, 0 degrees, 0 degrees coordinates. ```lat: 0.0 long: 0.0```

Comment: However, when I push the button, it outputs the correct coordinates for my location

Comment: That's what I was thinking, you use `addOnSuccessListener` but you are probably returning the values before the task completes

Comment: I think you're right, it looks like the function is running before even the build is complete or OpenGL is done rendering. Will try looking down that way, thanks